# Can't get data from mongoDB using promise in node js and toArray() error

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, promise

I am working on a shopping cart project in which I want to display the order details to user

the collection in mongoDB:

`{ "_id" : ObjectId("62dd044e056b97a9942a9b12"), "deliveryDetails" : { "phone" : "9120834756", "address" : "Kerala", "pincode" : "345678" }, "userId" : ObjectId("62dc5199cdc8e76d4f816d70"), "paymentMethod" : "COD", "products" : [ { "item" : ObjectId("62dae825ac724c0177c414ac"), "quantity" : 1 } ], "totalAmound" : 500, "status" : "Placed", "date" : ISODate("2022-07-24T08:35:26.993Z") }`

The promise section in js:

```
getUserOrder:(userId)=>{
        return new Promise(async(resolve,reject)=>{
            let orders=await db.get().collection(collection.ORDER_COLLECTION).findOne({userId:objectId(userId)}).toArray()
            console.log(orders);
            resolve(orders);
        })
    }
```

When using the above code it shows an error that `toArray()` is not a function and if I try by removing it it displays nothing to the page but in the console it prints '[object Object]'.

The router section in js:

```
router.get('/orders',verifyLogin, async(req,res)=>{
  let orders= await userHelpers.getUserOrder(req.session.user._id);
  res.render('user/orders',{orders,user:req.session.user});
})
```

The /orders call to this hbs page which has:

```
<tbody>
                        {{#each orders.products}}
                        <td scope="col">{{orders.date}}</td>
                        <td scope="col">{{this.deliveryDetails.address}}</td>
                        <td scope="col">{{this.deliveryDetails.pincode}}</td>
                        <td scope="col">{{this.deliveryDetails.phone}}</td>
                        <td scope="col">{{this.totalAmount}}</td>
                        <td scope="col">{{this.paymentMethod}}</td>
                        <td scope="col">{{this.status}}</td>
                        <td scope="col">
                            <a href="/view-order-products/{{this._id}}" class="btn btn-info">View Details</a>
                        </td>
                        {{/each}}
                    </tbody>
```

I want to display all this details to the user from the MongoDB collection called 'order' But it displays nothing, I cant find a solution, Please help to find a solution.

Comment: async/await in a new Promise executor is a very odd decision to have made - why not just make `getUserOrder` async? anyway, does `db.get().collection(collection.ORDER_COLLECTION).findOne({userId:objectId(userId)})` (with or without the toArray) even return a Promise? if not, then `await` does nothing

Comment: without toArray it returns [object Object]

Comment: waht if you try `let orders=(await db.get().collection(collection.ORDER_COLLECTION).findOne({userId:objectId(userId)})).toArray()`

Comment: Then it says: TypeError: (intermediate value).toArray is not a function

Comment: right ... so toArray is off the cards, and doesn't make sense if you "findOne" anyway ... so, `await db.get().collection(collection.ORDER_COLLECTION).findOne({userId:objectId(userId)}))` returns the **String** `"[object Object]"`? what is `typeof orders`

Comment: its object type

Comment: Hey can I use find instead of findOne the use toArray if needed?